# Socket Programming Cross Platform (PHP & Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I have created a socket server using PHP, the code is like this

**PHP**

```
function listen()
{
// set some variables
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = 25003;
// don't timeout!
    set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
    $input = trim($input);
    echo "Client Message : " . $input."\n";
// reverse client input and send back
    $output = strrev($input) . "\n";
    socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
// close sockets
    socket_close($spawn);
    socket_close($socket);
    listen();
}

set_time_limit(0);
listen();
```

Taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP

And I create the client socket using Javascript, like this

**Javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebSocketTest()
        {
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
                alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

                // Let us open a web socket
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:25003");

                ws.onopen = function()
                {
                    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                    ws.send("Message to send");
                    alert("Message is sent...");
                };

                ws.onmessage = function (evt)
                {
                    var received_msg = evt.data;
                    alert("Message is received...");
                };

                ws.onclose = function()
                {
                    // websocket is closed.
                    alert("Connection is closed...");
                };
            }

            else
            {
                // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
                alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sse">
    <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I run the PHP server, it's work, it's listening. 
And the I run the Javascript client, it's work, the PHP Server is receiving request from Javascript.

BUt the response from PHP is like this

[image]

I don't understand how to change the client message, let's say I want to send message just like "Hello", 
1. How can I call it from javascript so the PHP server is receive only "Hello" ?
2. Anyone can explain to me what is the function of each url like this ?

```
ws://localhost:25003/daemon.php
```

what is the second parameter? is this connect to my php file? because I try to locate to my php it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Socket server is OK, the problem is Javascript, it's sending a HTTP request and this send is a protocol for HTTP.

You can start the PHP Web Server on that port and answer that petisions whin Ajax queries.

Command line to start php like a Web Server

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:25003
```

The document root for WebServer is the same for PHP

Comment: I have start the php, but how to create request from js?
is my initialize for web socket is correct ? llike this 
`new WebSocket("ws://localhost:25003/server.php");`

Comment: If you want test and learn WebSockets maybe you need some like this socketo.me/docs,      
The response from Misyaath Mohammed have a usefull Link.